# Displaying Two images instead of one

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want to add a single image to the beginning of a JTextPane. Orginally I used:

```
textPane.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("icon");
```

But that didn't do anything at all, at least it didn't after I changed the document the textpane used.

So I used styles instead. Here's the code I used:

```
public QuotePanel(String quoted, DefaultStyledDocument quoteText) throws BadLocationException {
        initComponents(); //Netbeans GUI builder, should be irrevelant

        quotePane.setStyledDocument(quoteText); //QuotePane is a JTextPane declared as a global variable.
        Style icon = quoteText.addStyle("Quote Icon", null);
        ImageIcon quoteIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/posts/quotes.png"));
        StyleConstants.setIcon(icon, quoteIcon);
        quoteText.insertString(0, "Quotation Icon", icon);
        quoteText.insertString(1, (quoted + " said: " + "\n\n"), null);
}
```

This worked, but it had some interesting side effects. Then here is the main method I use to test the TextPane with:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        QuotePanel quote = null;

        try {
            DefaultStyledDocument test = new DefaultStyledDocument();
            test.insertString(0, "This is a test\n\n", null);
            JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
            Style styleRed = pane.addStyle("Red", null);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(styleRed, Color.red);
            test.insertString(test.getLength() - 1, "This is red\n", styleRed);
            Style styleBold = pane.addStyle("Bold", null);
            StyleConstants.setBold(styleBold, true);
            test.insertString(test.getLength() - 1, "This is Bold\n", styleBold);
            Style styleSmall = pane.addStyle("Small", null);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(styleSmall, 8);
            test.insertString(test.getLength() - 1, "This is small\n", styleSmall);


            quote = new QuotePanel("Quoted Person", test);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Oops, got an exception.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");

       frame.add(quote);
       quote.setVisible(true);
       frame.setSize(467, 126);
       frame.validate();
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

The output I get is this:

[image]

Why do the quotation symbols appear twice? I only have them appear once in the code. (Or at least I only have one line that adds them). I did do some research into why this occurred, but I couldn't find this problem anywhere else. There is no information on this problem on SO, as far as I can tell.

Comment: My answer below says how to fix the two icons showing, but I don't know why. If anyone knows why I would love to see that in an edit to my post or a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't figure out the exact answer, but I did figure out how to add a single image to a JTextPane.

I was on the right track with my first bit of code:

```
textPane.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("icon");
```

What I needed to know is that the `insertIcon()` method actually places the image where the selection is. So to properly place the icon, I needed to select the place I wanted to put it first.

So I used this code:

```
quotePane.select(0, 0);
quotePane.insertIcon(quoteIcon);
```

And that produced the proper output, with only one icon at the beginning of the JTextPane.